# Create custom links for private message in OG group

Tags: 7, organic-groups, privatemsg

I am using the module private messages to let users send messages to groups and other users. I would like to create a link where the recipient info is automatically filled with the Group title on the new message page.

Did any one try to work with private messaging groups and create the autocomplete links  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module for private message in group but it is sandbox module and for Drupal 6 only. You can customize it for Drupal 7

Just check this [Sandbox](http://drupal.org/sandbox/paolomainardi/1168586)

And refer this discussion also, it has nice roadmap regarding implementation of entire module. http://drupal.org/node/612664